# WPF bind IsEnabled property to List's size

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, isenabled

I want to bind the `IsEnabled` property (of a ribbon button) to a lists size. So when lists size is > 0 then `IsEnabled` is set to `true` else (if 0) it's set to false. How do you do that?

Answer (score 3):

Bind to the lists `Count` property and create your own `ValueConverter` to convert from an `int` to a `bool` (in your case returning `true` if the int is larger than 0 and `false` otherwise). Note that your list would need to raise a `PropertyChanged` event when the count changes - `ObservableCollection` does that for example.

Answer (score 2):

Either do it with a [DataTrigger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.datatrigger.aspx) that binds to the Count property of the list and sets IsEnabled to false if it is zero, or use a [ValueConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx).

*However take care, that a `List<T>` does not implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`, which informs about changes of the Count property. An `ObservableCollection<T>` will do*.